# Linux/Debian Apache2 mod_rewrite internal error

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian

i have some problems to setup my mod_rewrite for my Joomla-Site.
Im using Apache 2.2.22 on Debian.
Website is on Directory: */home/web/beta/*

What i did:

1) Commands:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite 
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/apache2
sudo chown -R www-data /var/run/apache2 
sudo a2enmod actions 
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

2) Then i setup following file: */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default*

```
<Directory /home/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride FileInfo
```

3) The htaccess file at path /home/web/beta/.htaccess i set:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

(I took the .htaccess from this site: http://www.joomla-security.de/downloads.html)

**Ok, now the Problem.**
As long as i set the AllowOverride to FileInfo i get following error message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at XXXXXXX.com Port 80

What i did wrong?
Can you help me please?

**EDIT: Error Log:**

> [Wed Nov 11 19:21:56 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Wed Nov 11 19:21:57 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Nov 11 19:21:57 2015] [alert] [client XX.XX.XX.198] /home/web/beta/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>
> [Wed Nov 11 19:21:58 2015] [alert] [client XX.XX.XX.198] /home/web/beta/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>
> [Wed Nov 11 19:21:59 2015] [alert] [client XX.XX.XX.144] /home/web/beta/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

It seems, from the errors you've posted, that you are trying to use the `Options` directive in .htaccess. To do that, you need to add `Options` to the `AllowOverride` directive in *000-default* (cf. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options).

So change:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

to

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
```

in *000-default*.

**Edit:**
And if the above doesn't work, try changing it to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

And if *that* doesn't work then it could mean that other configuration files are getting loaded after *000-default* and overwrite some of the directives.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, with your change i get the same error :(

Comment: Hmm. Could you try posting your entire htaccess (and make sure to remove any sensitive information if there is any)? For instance you could put it on pastebin.com.
Additionally, is there more in the error log?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GjA9YNFq here is the htaccess. Like i said, i took the file from joomla-security.de which runs on many websites

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple of additional possibilities. The reason I asked you to paste the file was because joomla-security.de offers 2 different versions and I didn't know which one you were using. :)